# How to create a *minimal* install USB for Centos 8

Tags: centos, kickstart, installer-anaconda

We're migrating our product line to Centos 8 and part of that is we need a "rescue" USB for our customers to use which re-installs the OS and applications.

Previously, we'd create a USB image with the `Centos6-Minimal.iso` and add our files and additional installers to the same image.  All in, that resulted in a 1.4GB image, which could be easily downloaded by our customers.

The "minimal install" instructions for Centos 8, however, say to download the `CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso` and select "minimal install" (which we can automate in our kickstart file).

However, `CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso` is 7.6GB as it includes a lot of software we don't need.

Since unetbootin et al no longer work, how can I create a small image for Centos 8 which contains and installs only the minimal files?

Answer (score 0):

You should always be able to create your custom iso installable image. There is a XML file containing all RPM package names. I do not remember its name, but I am sure you can find it.

Copy ISO image to your drive and edit XML file. Delete packages from XML that you do not need. I am not sure if you have to delete RPM files, too. Then you can create ISO image with the following instructions: https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos.

Then there is image builder for RedHat8/CentOS8. I believe this is also a way to do a custom ISO image.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/composing_a_customized_rhel_system_image/composer-description_composing-a-customized-rhel-system-image#composer-output-formats_composer-description

https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Composer/

Comment: Thanks, will check it out!